# com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd accumulates memory usage

Tags: android, memory-management, firebase, admob, interstitial

In **onCreate** of my activity I instantiate and load new interstitial

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
```

...

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID);
AdRequest adInterstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adInterstitialRequest);
```

then I log available memory with:

```
private void showFreeMemory() {
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        long availableMegs = mi.availMem / (1024 * 1024); 
        Log.i("Mem",availableMegs + " MB");
}
```

I can notice that every time i recreate (with this.recreate()) activity available memory is less then previous time. Without loading interstitial available memory does not change. So I've supposed that interstitial loaded contents are kept (in some way) in memory even if interstitial becomes eligible for GC. 
Is there a way to force interstitial to release memory?
Now I'm using

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0
```

but with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your interstitialAd using

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this.getApplicationContext());
```

instead of passing in the Activity.

Comment: Have you tried invoking the garbage collector prior to checking the available memory. Just because something becomes available for collection doesn't mean it will be collected immediately.

Comment: Yes, I invoke System.runFinalization and System.gc before checking and in activity onDestroy

Comment: In that case, I have nothing further to add.

Comment: I've found the "solution": boycotting AdMob and changing Ad provider.